# App Not Displaying Code after calling toString

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Hey guys I just created this program and its app. The App is supposed to call the toString method from the original class. Everything compiles but when I go to run the App nothing shows up. Any tips?
Here is the Television Class

public class Television
{

```
private int channel;
private int volume;
private boolean power;
private String[] channelName = {"CBS", "FOX", "DISCOVERY", "PBS", "HBO", "CNN", "DISNEY", "CNN", "TBS", "USA"};



//No argument constructor
public Television()
{
    channel = 1;
    volume = 0;
    power = false;

}


public void powerChange()
{
    this.power = !this.power;
}

public void setVolume(int vol)
{
    if (vol>10)
    {
    volume = 10;
    }else
    {
        volume = vol;
    }
    if (vol<0)
    {
    volume = 0;
    }

}

public void increaseVolume()
{
    volume++;
}

public void decreaseVolume()
{
    volume--;
}

public int getVolume()
{
    return volume;
}

public void setChannel(int ch)
{
    if(ch>10)
    {
    channel = 10;
    }else
    {
        channel = ch;
    }
    if(ch<1)
    {
    channel = 1;
    }
}

public void increaseChannel()
{
    channel++;
}

public void decreaseChannel()
{
    channel--;
}

public int getChannel()
{
    return channel;
}

public String getChannelName(int channel)
{

    if (channel==1)
    {
        return channelName[0];
    }
    else if (channel == 2)
    {
        return channelName[1];
    }   
    else if (channel == 3)
    {
        return channelName[2];
    }   
    else if (channel == 4)
    {
        return channelName[3];
    }   
    else if (channel == 5)
    {
        return channelName[4];
    }   
    else if (channel == 6)
    {
        return channelName[5];
    }   
    else if (channel == 7)
    {
        return channelName[6];
    }
    else if (channel == 8)
    {
        return channelName[7];
    }   
    else if (channel == 9)
    {
        return channelName[8];
    }   
    else 
    {
        return channelName[9];
    }   


}


public String toString()
{
    if(!power)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s :%d\n %s :%s\n%s :%d", "TV State", "OFF", "Channel No", channel, "Channel Name", getChannelName(channel), "Volume", volume);
    }
    else
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s :%d\n %s :%s\n%s :%d", "TV State", "ON", "Channel No", channel, "Channel Name", getChannelName(channel), "Volume", volume);
    }


}
```

}

And here is the App

```
//Television App
```

public class TelevisionApp
{

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //Creating Objects of class Television
    Television tv1 = new Television();
    //Television tv2 = new Television(5,5,false);

    //Invoking set methods
    tv1.powerChange();
    tv1.setVolume(3);
    tv1.setChannel(4);

    //Display first TV
    tv1.toString();

    //Display second TV
//  tv2.toString();



}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You need to output the String to the console. Use `System.out.println(tv1);`

Comment: No need to call `toString()` explicitly. Just `System.out.println(tv1)` is adequate. Answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks @theDazzler. Also, when I tried to create the second tv object an error occurred saying that the constructor could not be applied to the values, do you know why?

Comment: Yes you would need to add another constructor. Television(int one, int two, boolean value). The values you pass in need to match your constructor

Answer (score 0):

You just call toString method explicitly, it return a string value you formated, but you do not call println method to print the string value on Console.

If you want to see the content you can do the following things

```
System.out.println(tv1);
```

or

```
System.out.println(tv1.toString());
```